# Inclusion of space loop is a Serre fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fibration, loop-spaces

Let $i: X \longmapsto Y$ be an inclusion, and define $$\Omega_X Y:= \left\lbrace \gamma : I \longmapsto Y : \gamma(1) \in X \right\rbrace$$

Is it true that the map $$\bar{i} : \Omega_x Y \longmapsto Y$$

$$\gamma \longmapsto \gamma(0)$$

Is always a Serre Fibration?

Any solution would be appreciated, don't know where to start due to scarcity of hypothesis.

Comment: It is a Hurewicz fibration (and hence Serre). Use the well-known fact that $Y^I\rightarrow Y\times Y$, $\gamma\mapsto (\gamma(0),\gamma(1))$, is a fibration. Restrict (pullback) to the subspace $Y\times X$ to get a fibration $\Omega_XY\rightarrow Y\times X$ and take the composite with the projection $Y\times X\rightarrow Y$ (which is a fibration) to get $\overline i$. Alternatively just write down a lifting function for $\overline i$ directly.

Comment: @Tyrone Are you able to write that lifting function? I don't understand the first proof you wrote either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recall that a map $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a Hurewicz fibration if and only if it admits a lifting function $W_f\rightarrow A^I$, where $W_f$ is the mapping path space of $f$ and $A^I$ is the space of maps $I\rightarrow A$ in the compact-open topology. See, for instance, *Algebraic Topology*, E. Spanier, p. 92.

Below I'll work with the following definitions, letting
$$\Omega_XY=\{\ell:I\rightarrow Y\mid \ell(0)\in X\}$$
and $\overline i:\Omega_XY\rightarrow Y$ be defined by $\overline i(\ell)=\ell(1)$. Apologies for being obtuse.

Define the mapping path space $W_{\overline i}$ to be the pullback of the arrows
$$\Omega_XY\xrightarrow{\overline i} Y\xleftarrow{e_0} Y^I$$
where $e_0(m)=m(0)$. Thus
$$W_{\overline i}=\{(m,\ell)\in Y^I\times \Omega_XY\mid \ell(1)=m(0)\}.$$
By adjunction we identify $(\Omega_XY)^I$ with the subspace of $Y^{I^2}$ given by
$$(\Omega_XY)^I\cong\{f:I^2\rightarrow Y\mid f(0,t)\in X\;\forall \;t\in I\}.$$
Then a lifting function for $\overline i$ is a map $\lambda:W\rightarrow (\Omega_XY)^I$ satisfying
$$\lambda(\ell,m)(s,0)=\ell(s),\qquad \lambda(\ell,m)(1,t)=m(t).$$
To this end define
$$\lambda(\ell,m)(s,t)=\begin{cases}\ell((1+t)s)&s\leq\frac{1}{1+t}\\
m((1+t)s-1)&s\geq\frac{1}{1+t}.\end{cases}$$
This is the required lifting function.

Comment: Just two questions: $1.$ How can you assert so easily that the image under the adjunction is that subspace? $2.$ Where do you use the fact that you swapped the role of $\gamma(0),\gamma(1)$ wrt my notation?

Comment: 1. is a direct check. $\Omega_XY$ is a subspace of $Y^I$, so $(\Omega_XY)^I$ is a subspace of $(Y^I)^I\cong Y^{I\times I}$. To go from my definitions to yours use the homeomorphism $\ell\mapsto-\ell$, etc

Comment: Thank you, very nice. Just last question: in the reference you gave, i.e Spanier p.$92$, Theorem $8$, I'm unable to verify that $pF' = F$ and $F'(x,0) = f'(x)$  using just that $\lambda$ is just a right inverse. I proved it using that $\lambda$ is also a left inverse, and so the inverse of $\bar{p}$, while the definition is just right inverse. Are there any issues asking the lifting map to be the inverse? Are you able to prove that $pF' = F$ and $F'(x,0) = f'(x)$ using just $\lambda$ right inverse?

Comment: The condition $\overline p\circ\lambda=id$ gives $(e,\omega)=\overline p\circ\lambda(e,\omega)=(\lambda(e,\omega)(0),p\circ \lambda(e,\omega))$. Thus $\lambda(e,\omega)$ is a path starting at $e$ and covering $\omega$. In the (second part of) the proof of Th.8 $F'(x,-)=\lambda(f'(x),g(x))$ is a path starting at $f'(x)$ and covering $g(x)=F(x,-)$.

Comment: In general $\lambda$ will not be a two-sided inverse to $\overline p$. Rather the mapping path space $\overline B$ is only a retract of $E^I$. The lifting function $\lambda$ will be a homeomorphism if and only if $p$ is a fibration with unique path lifting (for instance if $p$ is a covering projection).